# C# populate combobox from Active Directory users

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am using this code to populate a combobox with Active Directory users but from time to time I get a COM exception at the 'for each' beside that the code works.

```
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry entry = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=DOMAIN, DC=local");
System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(entry);
mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";

foreach (System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult resEnt in mySearcher.FindAll())
{
   try
   {
       //DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry());
       System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry de = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry();
       comboBox2.Items.Add(de.Properties["GivenName"].Value.ToString() + " " + de.Properties["sn"].Value.ToString() + " " + "[" + de.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value.ToString() + "]");
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       // MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
   }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this or resolve the error?

Comment: Can you state exactly what the COM Exception Error is that you are getting..?

Comment: And probably the `InnerException` property. BTW, I do think `e.ToString()` is not the same as `e.Message`.

Comment: I don't know if this would cause an intermittent COMException, but you should be calling Dispose on all your IDisposable objects: DirectoryEntry, DirectorySearcher, SearchResultCollection (returned by FindAll()), ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing I'd do is include the property you want to grab from the result into the search result - that way, you don't have to do a `.GetDirectoryEntry()` call on each result:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=DOMAIN, DC=local");

DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";

// define the properties you want to be loaded into the search result object
mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("GivenName");
mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountName");
mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");

foreach (SearchResult resEnt in mySearcher.FindAll())
{
   try
   {
       string givenName = "";
       string samAccountName = "";
       string surName = "";

       // check if you got a value - not all properties have to be filled - 
       // and if they're not filled, they might be "null". 
       if(resEnt.Properties["GivenName"] != null && 
          resEnt.Properties["GivenName"].Count > 0) 
       {
           givenName = resEnt.Properties["GivenName"].Value;
       }

       // samAccountName is a *must* property - it has to be set.
       samAccountName = resEnt.Properties["samAccountName"].Value;

       if(resEnt.Properties["sn"] != null && 
          resEnt.Properties["sn"].Count > 0) 
       {
           surName = resEnt.Properties["sn"].Value;
       }

       comboBox2.Items.Add(givenName + " " + surName + " " + "[" + samAccountName + "]");
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       // MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
   }
}
```

The second point is: if you're on .NET 3.5 or newer, you can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching; also, working with the result set using the `UserPrincipal` objects is a lot easier, since things like `GivenName` and `Surname` are surfaced as properties on the `UserPrincipal`:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for any UserPrincipal 
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here 
    UserPrincipal foundUser = found as UserPrincipal;

    if(foundUser != null)
    {
       comboBox2.Items.Add(foundUser.GivenName + " " + foundUser.Surname + " " + "[" + foundUser.SamAccountName + "]");
    }
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.

Of course, depending on your need, you might want to specify other properties on that "query-by-example" user principal you create:

- `DisplayName` (typically: first name + space + last name)
- `SAM Account Name` - your Windows/AD account name
- `User Principal Name` - your "username@yourcompany.com" style name

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.

Comment: WOW !!! PrincipalSearcher ....much cleaner and simpler     with my method i was getting only the users with principal am getting also groups, applying a filter

Comment: i applied a filter with qbeUser.SamAccountName = ("");but can only get what is in the string "" . i wan to get only user

Comment: @ReavenSmith: if you use a `UserPrincipal` as your search "QBE" - then you should get only users, really. Otherwise, just ignore anything that's not a user..

Comment: am getting groups also, theres nothing like this in UserPrincipal: "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))"

Comment: like filter principal searcher by person only object

Answer (score 0):

Put the foreach loop inside the catch block of the try...catch statement.